# application not showing marker whose location is retrieving from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve location which is saved in firebase along with username and show it as marker in other activity. I am able to store latitude longitude with username. But it is not retrieving as required. I have tried everything, every solution but I am not able to detect error. Below is my code of retrieving locations. Please try to help me out this time I will be very thankful.

```
DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ServiceProvidersLocations").child("Locations").child(userid);

dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Locations loci=ds.getValue(Locations.class);
            Double lati=loci.getLatitude();
            Double longitude=loci.getLongitude();
            String pname=loci.getUserName();

           /* Double lati = Double.valueOf(ds.child("latitude").getValue(Locations.class).toString());
            Double longitude = Double.valueOf(ds.child("longitude").getValue(Locations.class).toString());
            String pname = ds.child("Locations").child("UserName").getValue(Locations.class).toString();*/
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lati, longitude);
            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(pname)
                    .snippet(pname)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                  /*  Intent intent=new Intent(LocationMapsActivity.this, UsersListR.class);
                    startActivity(intent);*/
                    return true;
                }
            });


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

This is my firebase structure.

[image]

Comment: what has this todo with javascript?

Comment: did you run the debugger to see the values that are being fetched from Firebase? Also, can you share to us your Locations class ? I think you should change your model name class, you can mismatch it with an implementation instead of a model

Comment: kindly provide your `Locations` model class too..

Comment: I have figured it out. the model name class was getting mismatch. Thanks to you all